# How to set $TERM to a value when running /bin/bash via command line?

Tags: bash

When I run the `/bin/bash` process with 2 parameters `-c` and `SomeUserInput`,

where SomeUserInput is `echo $TERM`

The output is

`xterm-256color`

Is there a way I can set the value of $TERM via **a command line parameter to `/bin/bash`** so the above invokation of `echo $TERM` would print something else that I specify?

(Yes, I've done a lot of digging in `man bash` and searching elsewhere, but couldn't find the answer; although I think it's likely there.)

Comment: Thank you very much to everyone for their help. Expressing gratitude on stackoverflow is always tricky for me (I'm not sure what's the best way?), but I just want you to know you've been helpful and I'm thankful for it. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, since you used double quotes, that prints the value of TERM in your current shell, not the bash you invoke. To do that, use `/bin/bash -c 'echo $TERM'`.

To set the value of TERM, you can `export TERM=linux` before running that command, set it only for that shell with either `TERM=linux /bin/bash -c 'echo $TERM'` (shell expression), or `/usr/bin/env TERM=linux /bin/bash -c 'echo $TERM'` (execve compatible (as for find -exec)).

Update:
As for your edit of only using command line parameters to `/bin/bash`, you can do that without modifying your input like this:

```
/bin/bash -c 'TERM=something; eval "$1"' -- 'SomeUserInput'
```

Comment: I'm not running /bin/bash from a shell, I'm running it from a C++ app via fork() and execl().

Comment: @DmitriShuralyov That'd be interesting to add such information in your question, as it may provide you better answers.

Comment: @DmitriShuralyov Your original question specifically states "I do the following in a terminal", which is not the same as using `fork()/execl()`.... Maybe the question should be updated...?

Comment: I wanted to see if there's a command-line way of setting this. If there were, it wouldn't matter how I'm running /bin/bash (i.e. it would be applicable to both terminal and fork/exec). But since there appears not to be (everyone provided workarounds), then yes, it matters, and I should mention it. Thank you for help; it seems execle() should do the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can either set the variable on your `.bashrc` file, or simply set with the bash invocation:

```
/bin/bash -c "TERM=something-else; echo $TERM"
```

Comment: I'd like not to modify the "echo $TERM" string if possible, since that's a variable which I don't know in advance.

If there's really no way to set $TERM via a command line argument, then I can fall back to just prepending the -c command with "TERM=something-else;" and hope it doesn't break anything...